# How to implent tf.nn.in_top_k in pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to implent `tf.nn.in_top_k` in pytorch. Here is the link of `tf.nn.in_top_k`,

```
tf.math.in_top_k(
    targets, predictions, k, name=None
)
```

It computed precision at k as a bool Tensor and will return a Tensor of type bool.

[tf.nn.in_top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/in_top_k)

I wonder whether there are similar api in pytorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no equivalent `in_top_k` function built into pytorch. It's relatively straightforward to write one. For example

```py
def in_top_k(targets, preds, k):
    topk = preds.topk(k)[1]
    return (targets.unsqueeze(1) == topk).any(dim=1)
```